# How do I display a global variable from one python file into another(as a Jinja Template)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a file called main.py wherein all my methods are saved. There is also a Global variable called 'bayy' which I want to display it in my jinja2 template(main.html)

To make things clear:
main.py

```
global bayy
```

main.html

```
<div>{{ bayy }}</div>
```

However this gives an error

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'bayy' is undefined
```

How do I go about solving this error?

**EDIT**: I am rendering the main.html in my main.py as

```
def stats()
    global bayy
    #rest of code
    return render_template('main.html')
```

Comment: how do you render `main.html` ?

Comment: @MarkRofail I have edited my question,you can find it there.

Comment: Try `render_template('main.html', bayy=bayy)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the global `g` to make `bayy` variable available globally in your templates.

refer to https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#application-globals

in `main.py`

```
from flask import g, ..

def stats()
    # global bayy  # You don't need this
    # rest of code

    g.bayy = 'bayy'

    return render_template('main.html')
```

in `main.html`

```
<div>{{ g.bayy }}</div>
```